# Android - Handset built in Developer Tools - "Show Cpu Usage" option meaning?

Tags: android, cpu-usage

Android handset shows a list of Developer Tools and Options (under Settings > Developer) to the user and can be displayed on the user's screen.  There is various data which gets displayed like: **6.002 / 6.48 / 8.23**,and **next lines shows some services running in the background** . What is the concept behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the developer site we have:

1. **Show CPU Usage:** Displays CPU meters at the top of the screen, showing how much the CPU is being used. The top red bar shows overall CPU usage, and the green bar underneath it shows the CPU time spent in compositing the screen. Here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html
2. Also we have an answer about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829592/826657

Comment: It looks like this has been removed from Android now. RIP.

Answer (score 22):

Numbers in the first row shows average CPU usage in time intervals 1 minute/5 minutes/15 minutes. Color bars shows how much time CPU spends in userspace(green), kernel(red), i/o(blue).

Comment: cpu usage in what?? percentage ?? @Leszek

Comment: It's measured as load average. See this Wikipedia article
for an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29

Comment: Number of proceses (or threads?) waiting for execution in queue. 1.8 is fine for 2 CPU, but means overload for 1cpu.

Answer (score 1):

It's specifically for developer purposes. They can monitor the handset's "behind-the-scenes" activity down to every bit. You can use this to monitor how your app or other apps are working with your device. You can see how much CPU they are using, the layouts in the UI and much much more. See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html).