# interpreting dumpsys cpuinfo

Tags: android, shell, cpu, dumpsys

Im looking for an explanation of result of command "dumpsys cpuinfo" in android shell.

```
:# dumpsys cpuinfo
Load: 17.78 / 16.97 / 16.29
CPU usage from 35983ms to 21604ms ago:
  97% 25268/com.firstprocess: 78% user + 19% kernel / faults: 19938 minor
  36% 25680/com.secondprocess: 19% user + 17% kernel / faults: 950 minor
  11% 25151/com.anotherprocess: 8.8% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 13794 minor 6 major
  18% 739/system_server: 13% user + 5.4% kernel / faults: 3803 minor 2 major
  14% 1242/android.process.media: 11% user + 2.7% kernel / faults: 2413 minor
  8.4% 333/adbd: 0.2% user + 8.2% kernel / faults: 1 minor
```

1. What is the meaning of numbers 17.78 / 16.97 / 16.29 in second line?
2. What mean numbers before process name? For example 97% or 36%? it can not be overall consumption of processor time, since sum of all processes would exceed 100%. Is it time consumed with one core of the processor?
3. What is the meaning of "78% user + 19% kernel"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information in dumpsys cpuinfo here is just a variation of the unix top command.

1) The load information is described here:

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

2) If you have more than one core (which I expect that you do), it will be more than 100%, so it is an average across all of the CPUs.

https://superuser.com/questions/575202/understanding-top-command-in-unix

3) Of the 97% of CPU, the process is spending 78% time in user space, and 19% in Kernel space.

Comment: In the article it talks about how 100% load is 1:1 with number of cores. Why are we seeing such high values on I assume a dual or quad core Android? Is the scale different or are they really overloaded?